# Multithreading using Taks / disable and enable buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I am looking for solution for disable login button while I am getting the answer from database. For multi-threading I am using `Task`. With a first `Task` I am doing invoke for connection, then I am creating a second `Task`for connecting them to not make `cross-exception`. 
As far I understood that in the first `Task` I cannot block button because getting exception that I cannot use resources from another thread.

If someone could have a look on the method which is responsible I would be grateful.

```
public void LoginIntoApplication(Button loginButton)
        {
            dbConn = new DataBaseConnection(loginWindow.loginBox.Text, loginWindow.passwordBox.Password);
            Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                // Get data from db
                dbConn.Connect();
            });
            Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(previouseTask =>
            {
                // Do smth with data
                loginButton.IsEnabled = false;
                var status = dbConn.OraCon;
                if (status.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    loginWindow.Hide();
                    testWindow = new TestWindow();
                    testWindow.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    loginButton.IsEnabled = true;
                }


            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            t.Start();
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wrap your loginButton.IsEnabled setter in a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or Invoke call - based on  behavior that you need.

Comment: Why are you using cold tasks and `ContinueWith` instead of `async/await`? This just makes your code a lot more complicated, *and* you end up with a fake asynchronous call. PS apart from the connection, your code has *no* database calls. Where are they?

Comment: That how its should look with `async/await` ?

Comment: What library are you using? ADO.NET connections do not have a `Connect` method. They have `Open` and [OpenAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.openasync(v=vs.110).aspx). You could write `await dbConn.OpenAsync();` and continue working on the UI thread once the asynchronous call to open the connection completes

Comment: Thats my own method which open connection with `OracleConnection` @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @DerpyUnKnow by encapsulating what doesn't need encapsulation you make asynchronous calls a lot harder. An ORM like EF or micro ORM like Dapper are appropriate abstractions. Putting a database-centric API on top of the already database-centric and *provider agnostic* ADO.NET, just makes your code harder to maintain.

Comment: So I just should do .OpenAsync(); and thats it ? @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to perform asynchronous operations is to use `async/await` and ADO.NET's asynchronous methods. The asynchronous methods run in the background using IO completion ports, so that they don't even require a background thread. The `await` keyword ensures that when they finish, execution returns to the UI thread :

```
public async Task LoginIntoApplication(Button loginButton)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn=new OracleConnection(myConnectionString))
        { 
            //OpenAsync runs on the background while the UI thread is released
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            //No exception means connection open
            //At this point we are back on the UI thread.
            loginButton.IsEnabled = false;
            loginWindow.Hide();
            testWindow = new TestWindow();
            testWindow.Show();

            var someCommand=new OracleCommand(myQuery,conn);
            //Run a query asynchronously
            using(var reader=await someCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
               //Work with the reader's results
            }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //Oracle refused the connection
        loginButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

If Open or OpenAsync succeeds you know the connection worked. If it doesn't it will throw an exception.

Note that you should **not** use any kind of global connection. Keeping a connection open for a long time accumulates locks and makes exception handling a lot harder. ADO.NET uses connection pooling to allow you to close a connection as soon as you finish using it, *without* paying the cost of actually creating a new connection. It's one of the most important scalability features for any database application.

Comment: Only thing i would change is to use a command instead of an event, the view shouldn't be logging in

Comment: @MikeT that's not an event. That's why it has an `async Task` signature. That's just a method. Speaking of improvements it would be best to use the MVVM model and update ViewModel properties instead of modifying the UI directly

Comment: i assumed the call was orignating from the buttons click event, if its not then it shouldn't be handling  the views controls directly, that is why ICommand defines the CanExecuteChanged event

Comment: @MikeT the OP didn't ask about the design of a WPF application. In that case, a ViewModel would be better, probably using a framework like Caliburn.Micro. In this case you wouldn't even need a Command, just the proper naming conventions for eg `CanLogin()` and `Login()`. The `Login()` method would *still* have to use `async/await` properly

Comment: Which is why i haven't said your answer is wrong, instead i just said that  i would improve your answer by using a command to move the code to the ViewModel and out of the view

Comment: Right answer! Just want to add that new Task(), and Task.Start, are almost NEVER necessary. Task.Run is more common, but even then the async / await keywords are by far the best approach.